# Are there any variants of pathological lying?

Tags: pathology

Are there any variants of pathological lying? As far as I understand it, that means either lying for no discernable reason, or to your advantage but a lot.

Are any other verbal behaviours themselves pathologised: pathological false confession, or pathological irony?